# Turn Excel Rows into Columns

Tags: excel

I need to reformat my data.

Right now, it looks something like this

```
PersonCol   DataCol
Person1     Data1
Person1     Data2
Person1     Data3
Person2     Data4
Person2     Data5
Person2     Data6
Person3     Data7
```

And I need to pivot it so it looks like this.  I need to turn the first row into column names, and have all of the data associated with that appear as lists below.

```
Person1       Person2       Person3
Data 1        Data4         Data7
Data2         Data5
Data3         Data6
```

I tried using the TRANSPOSE function, but that didn't work the way I needed it to.

I would do this manually.  However, the list needs to automatically update

Comment: what exactly didn't work about the `=TRANSPOSE()` ?

Comment: It gave me duplicate column names across the top.

It would look like this instead:

    Person 1     Person1        Person1
    Data1          Data2            Data3

Comment: To get what you want vba, will probably be your best choice.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you're proposing makes no sense from database / [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) standpoints, because it is unable to display the data correctly if it has more than one occurance of data per person.

Easiest and most logical structure would be to create a pivot table like so:

[image]

Where the count of the Data per person would be counted correctly, even upon multiple occurances.

Other option would be to replace duplicacies and use a `=COUNTIF()`

---

EDIT: I guess if you really wanted you could use something like this, but I wouldn't recommend it. Pivot table works just fine

[image]

Formula for `Data1` would look like this:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(D4:E$10, MATCH(1, E4:$E$10, 0),1), "")
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  I appreciate your help

Comment: @Inquisitor no problem, also unless you are waiting for some other answer / implementation, it would be nice of you if you accepted the answer so the question can be closed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Power Query` (aka `Get & Transform` in Excel 2016+). And if your source data changes, you can update the query.

- Select a cell in the table
- (In Excel 2016):  Data Ribbon, Get & Transform tab, from Table/Range
- In PQ UI:  Group By  `PersonCol`  Operation:=`All Rows`
- Add Column; Custom Column; formula:  `=Table.Column([Grouped],"DataCol")`
- Select the two-headed arrow at the right of the `Custom` column header

  - Extract values
  - I used semicolon as a delimiter, use something that does not appear in the data
- Split Column by delimiter (semicolon) --> the Data in new columns
- Remove the column of Tables where you previously Grouped the data
- Transpose the table
- Promote the first row to Headers
- Close and load to wherever you want

### M-Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"PersonCol", type text}, {"DataCol", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"PersonCol"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [PersonCol=text, DataCol=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.Column([Grouped],"DataCol")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Custom.1", "Custom.2", "Custom.3"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Custom.1", type text}, {"Custom.2", type text}, {"Custom.3", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Grouped"}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Columns"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Person1", type text}, {"Person2", type text}, {"Person3", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

### Results

[image]